# Create multiple sources according to descriminating index

Tags: java, rx-java

I have a stream which get gather data as response from its receptors.

so assuming i have n receptors, in the frame data received i'm able to know from which receptor index it was received and perform a filter and create a new source for each one as following.

-------a1------b1-----c1----a2-----a3----c2----b2-

-------a1-----------------a2-------a3-------------

---------------b1------------------------------b2-

----------------------c1---------------c2---------

Next step consists on taking from each lastest pair of values

here is my code sample :

```
 data.publish().refCount()
    .groupBy(frame -> frame.getIndex())
    .flatMap(Observable::toList)
    .buffer(2,1)
    .subscribe( delays -> {
        System.out.println(delays);
    });
```

A frame is a POJO :

```
public class Frame {
    private int index;
    private String message;
    private long timestamp;

    public Frame(int index, String message) {
        this.index = index;
        this.message = message;
        setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

How can i create a source for each group ? And after take item of each group pair by pair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the implemented method. Assuming you have an emitter and multiple receptors :

```
stream.groupBy(group -> group.geName())
    .map(receptor -> observeSource(receptor))
    .forEach(source -> {
        source
            .buffer(2, 1)
            .filter(items -> items.size() == 2)
            .map(pairs -> computeDelay(pairs.get(0), pairs.get(1)))
            .doOnNext(delay -> checkDelay(delay))
            .subscribe();
    });
}
```

I was missing the `forEach` operator to perform the desired operations on every receptor's source.

Answer (score 2):

Would be nice if you have printed an expected output for the given input set example, as your explanation of what the latest pair means is open to interpretation.
So if I assume that the latest pairs of {a1, a2, a3}: (a1, a2) and (a2, a3) then the following code would do what you want:

```
  private static Observable<List<String>> observeGrouped(Observable<String> str, String group) {
    return str.filter(s->s.substring(0, 1).equals(group)).buffer(2,1).filter(list->list.size() == 2);
  }


  @Test
  public void test() throws InterruptedException {

    Observable<String> src = Observable.just("a1", "b1", "c1", "a2", "a3", "c2", "b2").publish().refCount();

    String[] groups = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(groups.length);
    for (String group : groups) {
      observeGrouped(src, group).subscribe(System.out::println, e->{}, ()->latch.countDown());
    }
    latch.await();
  }
```

Output:

```
[a1, a2]
[a2, a3]
[b1, b2]
[c1, c2]
```

The above code is just a prototype to show a general approach. You can apply similar logic to your specific POJO. 
Let me know if you meant something else.

Comment: This approach works well but i want to take advantage of groupBy and don't have to keep track of my index in a list or string or whatever. Is it possible to have multiple sources from the groupedObservable

Comment: groupObservable is just helper that does create a new source each time you call it with your original root source by "connecting" to it. So you can put them to the list, array, whatever. Not sure what is a problem with having to use groupby. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: The problem is if i use the groupBy how can i split after into multipes distinct observables. If you can show a different approach with the same result with groupBy will be helpful